# How to fix the boot of an android tablet

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, boot, system-error

I have a [Plum link tablet](http://www.gsmarc.com/plum/link/) that when it is booting doesn't load the OS. When it tries loading the OS it gives me this error: `Unfortunately system UI has stopped`, and then cannot complete loading the OS; it just shows me that message and no more.

I've try everything: I wiped the data, and nothing. What else can I do?

---

**Edit:** <sup>Some facts integrated from below comments (by Izzy)</sup>

- factory-reset (done via the recovery menu) did not help
- what broke it was most likely increasing the screen resolution (DPI?) too much, so the config now holds invalid values (does anybody know if that is revertable e.g. via recovery menu + ADB, or something alike?)
- last item indicates that `root` access is available on the device

Comment: I've just edited your question to make it easier to understand (I hope I've got that right?), and added a link to device information. Just a question for clarification: by "I wiped the data", are you talking of a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)? If not, you might want to give this a try. If a factory-reset doesn't solve your issue (try also booting with the microSD card removed), you might need to turn it in for service, or ask them if they've got a "software fix" (usually a firmware update).

Comment: So did you try a factory-reset? If so: did it solve your issue? Still not clear :)

Comment: I try to reset the tablet pressing the volume up + power key and didn't work

Comment: What reset is that? I didn't know that some devices get reset just by that (or any other) key combination. You could go into the recovery menu, and select "factory reset" there -- just to be sure.

Comment: Whne you pressed Volume Up + power key and hold comes a menu to update the cache system, wipe user data, wipe cache data and load a new firmware i choose wipe user data, that i think is the factory reset.

Comment: Correct -- and that menu is the "recovery menu". OK, in this case you should ask your vendor for an update (even if it's the same version). Have you tried to remove the microSD card and see if it boots up then?

Comment: It doesn't have microSD

Comment: Then this leaves you with the service, as described. Nothing more you can do, sorry. What did you do before the device broke? Flashing some custom ROM maybe?

Comment: No, i try to expand the resolution more.

Comment: Oh. That perfectly explains your problem: you set it too high, so the GUI can no longer load. But to do that, your device must be rooted. Which means, you could flash another ROM as well. Or, if you've got a custom recovery, and hopefully did a Nandroid backup before, you can simply restore that. Otherwise you will have to explain to the service how that happened -- and have to pay them for repair, as (outside the EU) rooting voids your warranty.

Comment: How i can flash another ROM?

Comment: First find it (see e.g. [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)). On the page from where you can download it, it most times has a description on how to flash it. Methods and tools differ a little between devices, and I don't know yours. As you always only give us "snippets", I e.g. still don't know if you have a custom recovery (CWM, TWRP, ...) installed on your device; they e.g. enable you to flash `update.zip` files from SDCard.